# How to fix could not load file or assembly exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having two projects test1 and test2 inside a single solution.
What my requirement is: I want to execute test2.exe from test1.exe
So what i have done is : I added test2.exe as a Resource to test1 and on test1-button_click invoked the test.exe but getting the below error even after i added the dll as a Resource inside test2.

[image]

Comment: You should generally not embeed compiled binaries within your main program, you just deploy both files together and the runtime does the rest. For embeeding you must take additional steps yourself to ensure the dependency is there, as the runtime won't look into resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new C# class library project and move the logic of test2 into it. Then you could add a project reference of this new class library to test1.

This is a bit of refactoring your solution.